# Why laravel passport create new token with each login process?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I Just have my question why `Laravel passport` create a new token with each login or register process?

My database now ( just for testing)

[image]

notice with every registration process creating a new token, imagine if I have 100,000 users and every user has to assume 10 tokens, will this affect performance?

> I'm new on Laravel passport

Comment: You need to explain in more detail, how you do it, how you integrate it, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tokens that Passport generates are meant to be long lived; Notice the `expires_at` column it shows about one year.

Passport is typically used by First party app like you own SPA/mobile app or by a third party Machine/API to get access to your app. This Oauth procedure (register/login) may occur only once per long time, for example a mobile app using your API: the users won't enter their credentials every time to open the app; instead the token is saved to mobile app storage and it's already long lived.

If you use your app like The [Passport docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/passport) explains and suggests you won't end up with all these tokens.

Another thing you should consider running a scheduler to purge the tokens as the docs states:

```
# Purge revoked and expired tokens and auth codes...
php artisan passport:purge

# Only purge revoked tokens and auth codes...
php artisan passport:purge --revoked 

# Only purge expired tokens and auth codes...
php artisan passport:purge --expired
```

Finally, [Sanctum "previously Airlock"](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/sanctum) is here ✌
I suggest you take a look at the docs and you will notice it's much simpler than Passport and probably what you need.